# Generating unique ID for clients on a system running over a LAN in C#

Tags: c#, .net, primary-key

I've a simple client registration system that runs over a network. The system is supposed to generate a unique three digit ID (primary key) with the current year concatenated (e.g. 001-2013). However, I've encountered the problem that the same primary keys being generated when two users from different computers (over a LAN) try to register different clients.

What if the user cancels the registration after an ID is already generated? I've to reuse that ID for another client. I've read about static variable but it didn't solve my problem. I really appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Post the current logic that you are using. Also, do you really need to re-use the cancelled registrations? If it only needs to be unique, you could probably discard them

Comment: Is the ID stored in a database? And if so, is it possible to generate the ID in the db when inserting the row?

Comment: Does it have to be three digit?  Could you just use GUIDs?

Answer (score 2):

Unique and sequential IDs are hard to implement. To completely achive it you would have to serialize commiting creation of client information so ID generated only when data is actually stored, otherwise you'll endup with holes when something wrong happened during submittion.

If you don't need strict sequential numbers - giving out ranges of ID (1-22, 23-44,...) to each system is common approach. Instead of ranges you can give out lists of IDs to use ({1,3,233,234}, {235,236,237}) if you need to use as many IDs as possible.

Comment: +1 The hi/lo approach (use X bytes prefix that is fetched, give lowest bytes yourself - i.e. segmenting) is standard. For things like invoice numbers, put them into a database without (not commited) then use a SP to commit them financially. THis works nice - my own accounting allows a non-commited invoice per customer, so I can just add items there, then close it by accounting for it.

Answer (score 2):

Issue:

1. New item -001 is created, but not saved yet
2. New item -002 is created, but not saved yet
3. Item -001 is cancelled

What to do with ID -001?

The easiest solution is to simply not assign an ID until an item is definitely stored.

An alternative is, when finally saving an item, you look up the first free ID. If the item from step 2 (#2) is saved before the one from step 1, #2 gets ID -001. When #1 then gets saved, the saving logic sees that its claimed ID (-001) is in use, so it'll assign -002. So ID's get reassigned.

Finally you can simply find the next free ID when creating a new item. In the three steps described above, this'll mean you initially have a gap where -001 is supposed to be. If you now create a new item, your code will see -001 is unused and will assign that to the new item.

But, and that totally depends on your requirements which you didn't specify, now -001 was created later in time than -002, I do not know if that is allowed. Furthermore at any given moment you can have a gap in your numbering where an item has been cancelled. If it happens at the end of a reporting period, this will cause errors (-033, -034, -036).

You also might want to include an auto-incrementing primary key instead of this invoice number or whatever it is.

Comment: This is great. But, I want the user to see the ID on the screen at the time of registration so that it can be used for paper work. Is that even possible?

Comment: @user758961 not using the second solution, see the third I added.